# Sorbet: Instance variables must be declared inside `initialize`

Tags: ruby, sorbet

Getting - Instance variables must be declared inside `initialize` even though I have already declared the instance variables inside initialize.

I am using `typed: strict` to type check my ruby code. One of the instance methods I am using an instance variable `@updated`. Sorbet threw an error - "Use of an undeclared variable". I created an initialize method to declare it. And then "Use of an undeclared variable" got replaced with "Instance variables must be declared inside `initialize`"

```
sig{returns(<<redacted>>)}
def initialize
  @updated = T.let(Time.now, Time)
  self
end
```

The error is -

```
Instance variables must be declared inside `initialize` https://srb.help/5005
    39 |       @updated = T.let(Time.now, Time)
```

Expected - There shouldn't be any error as instance variable is declared in `def initialize`

Edit: I have reproduced this in [Sorbet Playground](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20strict%0Aclass%20A%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7Breturns(Integer)%7D%0A%20%20attr_accessor%20%3Ax%0A%20%20%0A%20%20sig%20%7Bparams(y%3A%20Integer).void%7D%0A%20%20def%20initiazlize(y)%0A%20%20%20%20%40x%20%3D%20y%0A%20%20end%0A%0A%20%20sig%7Breturns(Integer)%7D%0A%20%20def%20simple_operation%0A%20%20%20%20%40x%20%3D%205%0A%20%20%20%20%40x%0A%20%20end%0A%0Aend)

```
# typed: strict
class A
  extend T::Sig

  sig {returns(Integer)}
  attr_accessor :x

  sig {params(y: Integer).void}
  def initiazlize(y)
    @x = y
  end

  sig{returns(Integer)}
  def simple_operation
    @x = 5
    @x
  end
end

# -- error
editor.rb:10: Instance variables must be declared inside `initialize` https://srb.help/5005
    10 |    @x = T.let(y, Integer)
            ^^
Errors: 1
```

Comment: _Sidenote:_ it makes zero sense to return `self` as well as anything else from `initialize`. The returned value is effectively discarded.

Comment: What line is 39? Please also show the whole code of this class, including declaration.

Comment: Also, it would be great if you can recreate the same error in https://sorbet.run and post the link to it here.

Comment: Attaching a link to sorbet playground - https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20strict%0Aclass%20A%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7Breturns(Integer)%7D%0A%20%20attr_accessor%20%3Ax%0A%20%20%0A%20%20sig%20%7Bparams(y%3A%20Integer).void%7D%0A%20%20def%20initiazlize(y)%0A%20%20%20%20%40x%20%3D%20y%0A%20%20end%0A%0A%20%20sig%7Breturns(Integer)%7D%0A%20%20def%20simple_operation%0A%20%20%20%20%40x%20%3D%205%0A%20%20%20%20%40x%0A%20%20end%0A%0Aend

Comment: You need to declare the instance variable inside the `initialize` method, not the `initiazlize` method which is what you have (note the extra `z`).

Answer (score 4):

It appears you've maybe typo'd the `initialize` method name. [fixed example](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20strict%0Aclass%20A%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7Breturns(Integer)%7D%0A%20%20attr_accessor%20%3Ax%0A%20%20%0A%20%20sig%20%7Bparams(y%3A%20Integer).void%7D%0A%20%20def%20initialize(y)%0A%20%20%20%20%40x%20%3D%20T.let(y%2C%20Integer)%0A%20%20end%0A%0A%20%20sig%7Breturns(Integer)%7D%0A%20%20def%20simple_operation%0A%20%20%20%20%40x%20%3D%205%0A%20%20%20%20%40x%0A%20%20end%0A%0Aend)